# Change user and group of all files in project after git pull

Tags: git, hook

The user and group are always changed to `root:root` if I execute `git pull` or `git checkout`

So I created the file `.git/hooks/post-merge` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

chown -R mycompany:www /srv/www/vhosts/mycompany

exec git-update-server-info
```

The file has execute permission

But it does not work, nothing changes after `git pull` was called.

Comment: It's an example like a in gitlab or github when you see merge. - shows what lines are removed, + shows what lines are added.

Comment: Ok I see, so his example does not work. I removed it from my question.

Comment: You can try his example, just remove `+` and `-` and `-   git pull HUB master` line and try it. Also change branch names.

Comment: Does not work. Why is my code not getting called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check: is your hook executable?
As [in this example](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/7996717):

> Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make it executable then put it into `.git/hooks/`.

Then add at least an echo in it, to check if it is executed or not.

Note that the hook will only run after a successful merge, meaning if the pull result in a fast-forward merge (HEAD moves, no actual merge needed) the hook would not run.

An alternative would be to try and [use setuid/setgid](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits) to force to process (Git, as root) to run as the right user (pre-requisite: chown to set the right user/group for those files)

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yes the file is executable as I wrote earlier, I also added echo statements but nothing is printed.

Comment: so you say if `git pull` returns `Already up-to-date` then the hook will not get called? Only if there will be new files?

Comment: @Black Inly if there are new files *to be merged*. If the pull only add new commits on top of your commits (fast-forward merge), the hook would not need to run.

Comment: but thats also a use case where I need it to run, because my file owner and group are always overwritten with `root:root`. Isn't it possible?

Comment: @Black Then you would need to define an alias that would chain the pull and the chown.

Comment: no this is not a good idea, since I have multiple projects on the same server which have other users. This would change their users to the one defined in my alias if I execute `git pull`.

Comment: Maybe I have to edit the git source code to change the behaviour. But this would be really hacky. So I guess I can accept your solution.

Comment: @Black Would a `setgid` be more practical? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29838913/6309: at least the group would be correct.

Comment: Thx for `setgid` interesting. But It won't solve my problem because the user is the problem. My NetBeans can't overwrite files with user root if I synch or upload, but if I do `git pull` then all changed files will be set to user root. Another solution would be to change to the user  of the project with `su`, but this is not comfortable enough for me.

Comment: @Black Maybe this can be appliued to uid as well: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits